# DKIM signing using Mimekit, signing with custom headers

Tags: c#, dkim, mailkit, mimekit

I wanted to know if it possible to sign using custom headers.

So my code snippet is something like this.

```
message.Headers.Add("X-Feedback-ID", "XXXXX -  **XXXXXX**");

string privatekey = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("my.key");

   using (Stream s = GenerateStreamFromString(privatekey))
            {
                var headersToSign = new[] { HeaderId.From, HeaderId.To, HeaderId.Subject, HeaderId.ReplyTo, HeaderId.MimeVersion, HeaderId.ContentType };
                var signer = new DkimSigner(s, "mydomain.com", "myd");   
                message.Sign(signer, headersToSign, DkimCanonicalizationAlgorithm.Relaxed, DkimCanonicalizationAlgorithm.Relaxed);

            }
```

I can't figure out an easy way to add the header below since it doesn't have an ID:

```
Headers["X-Feedback-ID"]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this, I think that it is not very elegant :( though.

I had to edit the HeaderID.cs file, not sure if the owner of the project would approve.

```
        XStatus,

    /// <summary>
    /// The X-Feedback-ID header field.
    /// </summary>
    [HeaderName("X-Feedback-ID")]
    XFeedbackID,
```

Comment: You could actually just use `HeaderId.XMailer`.

Comment: @jstedfast, that was a place-holder for a custom header, the actual header is X-FeedbackID, sorry that it wasn't made clear.

Comment: I think, there is still a problem @jstedfast, if I use a custom header like "X-Feedback-ID" then it gives  an exception "the list of headers should not use unknown headers" :(.

Comment: @jstedfast, do you think you could add the header

 /// <summary>
    /// The X-Feedback-ID header field.
    /// </summary>
    [HeaderName("X-Feedback-ID")]
    XFeedbackID,

I am told that this is a standard header that is used for feed-back loop reporting.

Comment: It's not a standard header. Standard headers do not begin with X-. I've added new Sign() methods that take a string list instead, but I won't be making another release for another month or so.

Comment: @Krishnan Venkiteswaran  Can you show Feedback-ID code in brief as like your question.